# WordPress login is not showing , there is warning?

Tags: login

There is problem , just add Gutenberg plugin

[image]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

That error means you need to investigate what is happening on line 22 in functions.php of your current theme (centilium-masonry). Without knowing what's happening in the code it won't be possible to help further.

If you think the problem may be the Gutenberg plugin then you need to either FTP into your site or use a file manager to access your files and delete that plugin. Your web host can help with that.